# I need to find environment file inside my shell scripts

Tags: shell

I have several environment file, which end with .env. I want to find them in existing on the same directory shell scripts. I do

```
for i in [ ls -1 *env ]    
do
    grep $i *.sh >> ttt    
done
```

It shows me the following errors:
grep: RE error 49: [ ] imbalance.
grep: illegal option -- 1
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Could you please tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

#### Could you please tell me where is my mistake?

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 3:
    grep $i *.sh >> ttt    
         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
            ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.

$
```

Source [ShellCheck finds bugs in your shell scripts.](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @osamuyl Do you need more help? If this was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept it. See [accept an answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).